# how to edit a url with embedded query passing more than 1 value in key value pair

Tags: php, r, url

I am trying to scrape the following url but it is extremely slow as I have to do a sequential scrape by changing the key-value pair and loading a fresh page for every value. Note key is the same, only value needs to change.

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(jsonlite)
    
readr::read_lines("http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=364334") %>% fromJSON %>% as.data.table
```

The problem is I have thousands of BillIDs and loading the page one by one will take hundreds of hours.

I tried some combinations of query string changes but none were accepted.

```
 "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=364334,100025"

 "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=364334 AND 100025"
```

I get a syntax error returned by the web server:
`pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near`

I guess I am unfamiliar with url formats and that's why I am unable to come up with the correct query string. Following are 10 random billids. Can you try to fit them in one query?

```
c("100025", "147025", "6025", "119025", "118025", "98025", "123025", 
"224025", "313025", "18025")
```

Comment: pg_query, im presuming is a php function, but the rest is something else

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the rest is R code. If you can make the URL (with multiple IDs) run successfully in the browser I will do the remaining fix in the code.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: If you can design the url string that it cracks the single ID barrier (you can use one more billing ID from the list I gave - copy and paste to the browser url) I will accept and upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create each url separately with `sprintf`/`paste0`.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(readr)

urls <- sprintf('http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=%s', billIDs)
urls
# [1] "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=100025"
# [2] "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=147025"
# [3] "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=6025"  
# [4] "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=119025"
# [5] "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=118025"
# [6] "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=98025" 
# [7] "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=123025"
# [8] "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=224025"
# [9] "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=313025"
#[10] "http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID=18025"
```

Then you can use `lapply` to read them.

```
result <- lapply(urls, function(x) read_lines(x) %>% fromJSON)
```

Comment: this is what I am already doing. The problem is this is too slow. It loads each page one by one. If you read my question I already have the sequential pages solution but this will take many many hours for my thousands of IDs. I want the url to be modified so we can read multiple IDs in one load.

Answer (score 0):

A better option may be to do this in parallel

-packages

```
library(jsonlite)
library(readr)
library(future.apply)
library(glue)
```

-code

```
# // create the urls
urls <- as.character(glue('http://218.248.45.166:8092/vssWB',
   '/vss00CvStatusData.php?pAction=LoadDetails&pWorkBillID={billIDs}')) 
# // now set the number of workers
future::plan(multiprocess, workers = length(urls))
options(future.globals.maxSize= +Inf) 
out <- future.apply::future_lapply(urls, function(x) read_lines(x) %>%
   fromJSON)
future::plan(sequential)
```

#### data

```
billIDs <- c("100025", "147025", "6025", "119025", "118025", "98025", "123025", 
     "224025", "313025", "18025")
```

Comment: This looks interesting @akrun. I never knew the `future.apply` package. But on executing the first line I get this ominous warning: `
Warning message:
[ONE-TIME WARNING] Forked processing ('multicore') is disabled in future (>= 1.13.0) when running R from RStudio, because it is considered unstable. Because of this, plan("multicore") will fall back to plan("sequential"), and plan("multiprocess") will fall back to plan("multisession") - not plan("multicore") as in the past.` 
A basic question: How will this speed up the scraping, as the server bottleneck stays.